# Can't pull private Docker hub repo

Tags: macos, docker

Initially I couldn't do this because I realised I didn't have the correct permissions for my Docker hub user. After fixing the permissions I was able to see the repo in the web UI. However when doing a docker pull I'm getting the following error:

> Error response from daemon: repository XXX/YYY not found: does not exist or no pull access

I tried creating it via Kitematic and it worked, so it seems like permissions are working fine.

Anyone have any ideas why the CLI is still saying I don't have pull access?

Comment: did you `docker login` first?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, even did a logout and login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you login private registry server first.

```
docker login -u username -p password <private>.domain.com
```

Comment: I stand corrected. Turns out there was something wrong with docker login when no parameters was specified. After doing ```docker login docker.io -u <username>``` it started working. Though now it doesn't seem to be keeping the session, but that's another issue.

Comment: I ran into the same issue again this morning and reverted to the previous Docker for Mac build 17661 (fortunately I still had it in the Trash)

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.. I don't understand why this mattered so someone please comment if you understand how this resolved the same issue for me.

Essentially, instead of using `docker image push` (`docker push`) to create the repository on my docker hub account, **I created the repository on my docker hub account for my image, and THEN pushed my image up to that repository** on docker hub.

So.. for example. Say I build an image:

```
docker build -t nicholasaaronbrady/testnode
```

I then create the repository `nicholasaaronbrady/testnode` on docker hub and THEN I push my repository up.

```
docker image push nicholasaaronbrady/testnode
```

I noticed that if I do it this way, the tag's image size is 22MB; however, if I pushed it up without creating the image first on docker hub , the size of the tag was 0B. This is what clued me in that there was some issue with pushing the repository up to docker hub.

I have a guess that it is because I already maxed out the number of private repositories I can have under my credentials and proceeded to push up another image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow how this affects the ```docker pull``` issue I'm having

Comment: when I was using docker pull, your error was the error I was getting. What fixed it for me was changing how I pushed the image up to docker hub. When I pushed it up as I described above, I was able to use `docker pull` without getting the error we both had.

Comment: It might be a different issue for me as I can see the tag's image size is not 0 and I am able to pull using kitematic. I just can't seem to do it using the docker cli, which is strange because I'd assume kitematic is using the same commands.

Comment: Ah okay, well good luck. hopefully my post helps someone else.